# GUIDE4YOU - layermenu extend with show/hide text features

Tags: openlayers-3, guide4you

Is there a way to extend the layermenu?

For **featurelayers** users should be able to click on a image or button to show/hide the text of the features of that specific layer.

Showing or hiding the text of a feature is handled by the stylefunction on base of the current ''**showfeaturetext**'' property of the layer.

Is this possible with the current code?

Kind regards,

Sam

Answer (score 0):

You could extend the layerselector if you are creating custom guide4you builds (see https://github.com/KlausBenndorf/guide4you#how-to-install-and-build-guide4you and https://github.com/KlausBenndorf/guide4you/wiki/How-to-create-an-own-guide4you-module) and overwrite the buildLayerButton method. Sadly the buildLayerButton does not return the button, which would make it a little more straightforward.

```
export class MyLayerSelector extends LayerSelector {
    buildLayerButton (layer, $target) {
        super.buildLayerButton(layer, $target)
        $target.children(':last-child') // <- this should be your button as a jquery object
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying this without success.

These are my steps:

1. I made a new file in the source dir: (.\src\controls\MyLayerSelector.js)
2. Content:

   import $ from 'jquery'

   import {LayerSelector} from './LayerSelector'

   export class MyLayerSelector extends LayerSelector {
       buildLayerButton (layer, $target) {
           super.buildLayerButton(layer, $target)
           $button = $target.children(':last-child') // <- this should be your button as a jquery object
       }
   }
3. Edit entry.js. I've added this line:

   import { MyLayerSelector } from '../../src/Controls/MyLayerSelector'
4. Edit entry.js. I've also added this line:

   window.createG4U = function (target, clientConf = defaultClientConf, layerConf = defaultLayerConf) {
     return createG4UInternal(target, clientConf, layerConf, [
       new MyLayerSelector()
     ])
   }
5. NPM run build output:

warnings:
[ './src/Controls/Control.js\nThere is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.\nThis can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.\nRename module if multiple modules are expected or use equal casing if one module is expected.',
  './src/controls/Control.js\nThere is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.\nThis can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.\nRename module if multiple modules are expected or use equal casing if one module is expected.',
  './src/Controls/LayerSelector.js\nThere is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.\nThis can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.\nRename module if multiple modules are expected or use equal casing if one module is expected.',
  './src/controls/LayerSelector.js\nThere is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.\nThis can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.\nRename module if multiple modules are expected or use equal casing if one module is expected.',
  './src/Controls/ControlLogicMixin.js\nThere is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.\nThis can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.\nRename module if multiple modules are expected or use equal casing if one module is expected.',
  './src/controls/ControlLogicMixin.js\nThere is another module with an equal name when case is ignored.\nThis can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic.\nRename module if multiple modules are expected or use equal casing if one module is expected.' ]

When I ignore these warnings I get a javascript error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'selectL10N' of undefined